# Why doesn't layout file load properly on orientation change?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-edittext

I have an activity with a TextView and EditText line for user input. The EditText is embedded in the layout file.  Unfortunately, on orientation change from portrait to landscape, the view is not correct as the layout file is not fully loading. The TextView, background colors and toolbar of the layout file are not loading. Only the EditText hint shows and the background color shown defaults to white. I tested on a Samsung Galaxy S3 and a Genymotion emulator with the same bad result. Lastly, when the device or the emulator is rotated from landscape mode back to portrait, the portrait view layout loads correctly.  Any ideas on why this is happening?

Activity java file:

```
public class CardViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private ListenerEditText myListenerEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.cardviewinput);

myListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(R.id.CEditText);
```

EditText java file:

```
public class ListenerEditText extends EditText {    
...
```

Layout xml file:

```
...
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FF0000"        >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text=" To Do item:  "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <com.example.jdw.secondscreen.ListenerEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/CEditText"
        android:inputType="text|textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:hint="Type a new item here"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext" >

        <requestFocus />
    </com.example.jdw.secondscreen.ListenerEditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you viewed your layout in landscape orientation in the IDE design view to confirm it displays correctly?

Comment: Yes when switched to landscape it displays correctly.

The error seems to be that because the EditText line of the UI has focus, on orientation change to landscape loads only the EditText and not the full layout file.  Thoughts?

Comment: I assume you don't have an alternative layout in a folder such as res/layout-sw600dp? Does the landscape layout load correctly if the app is started in landscape orientation initially?

Comment: Not sure but another potential source of the error may be that I am setting the soft keyboard to "stateVisible" in the Manifest file so that it is always available for user input on the View.  I am wondering if that is somehow interfering with the View loading correctly on the orientation change.

Comment: No I don't have any alternative layouts.  Also, the view shows correctly starting the app in landscape mode.  I then switch to portrait and it loads correctly.  When I then switch back to landscape mode the view does not show correctly.

Comment: Best approach is to start simplifying the layout to identify to root cause. I would try changing the ListenerEditText to a regular EditText, also try removing <requestFocus /> and also remove the stateVisible setting in the manifest. Also take a good look at your logcat output after the rotation, it may include some runtime warning or error to give you a hint.

Comment: Ok, so this is interesting:  I removed the 'android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" code from the <activity> in the Manifest and now the View after orientation to landscape loads properly.  Any thoughts on why that would not allow the View to load correctly on orientation change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79175/discussion-between-brentm-and-ajw).